# skinny tables with person accounts

Tags: performance, person-accounts

We are currently experiencing performance issues when performing SOQL queries on the account table(8.5M records) and especially our person accounts(95% of our accounts are person accounts) have already added custom indexes on fields that are often used as query parameters and are now investigating solutions like skinny tables.

but since skinny tables cannot contain formula fields or fields derived from other objects(lookup) we are not sure if these restrictions also apply on person accounts.

Has anyone already have experience with skinny tables and person accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reaching out to support it seems that they can create skinny tables with person accounts where fields from both the contact as the account object are used.